# SharePoint Transferring pages to Production

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am building an internet site, using my local machine as the development box (I have MOSS 2007 installed).
I have a custom master page, packaged in a WSP, so I may use STSADM on the production server to install it.
I have made some pages via SPD (on my local machine) and put them in the "Pages" gallery.
What is the recommended way to get these pages to production.
Also, is the process the same when I make edits to current pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving master pages to production , best way is wsp packaging and stsadm .
Pages gallery is a ducument library .Ifyou have access in production server , you can upload edited pages in the production pages library so that the changed files will move to production.